# CPP DLL creation in VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dllimport, dllexport

I am new to Vs and DLL project creation. After gone throught the MS dll creation website, started to create the dll for my application.

I have attached .h and source cpp file. I could able to create the dll but coundnt find the exported function in dependency viewer of the created dll.

I am currently having no idea in resolving this error. Some insights would be helpful in taking forward this.

Thanks in advance!

header file

```
#pragma once

#ifdef MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;




struct BoundingBox {
    std::array<uint32_t, 2> top_left;
    std::array<uint32_t, 2> bottom_right;

    BoundingBox(std::array<uint32_t, 2> top_left, std::array<uint32_t, 2> bottom_right)
        : top_left(top_left), bottom_right(bottom_right) {}

    std::string to_string() const {
        return "top left: " + std::to_string(top_left[0]) + ", " + std::to_string(top_left[1]) + ", bottom right: " + std::to_string(bottom_right[0]) + ", " + std::to_string(bottom_right[1]);
    }
};
struct ADROutput {
    BoundingBox bounding_box;
    float score;
    int class_id;

    ADROutput(int class_id, float score, std::array<std::array<uint32_t, 2>, 2> bounding_box)
        : bounding_box(BoundingBox(bounding_box[0], bounding_box[1])), score(score), class_id(class_id) {}

    std::string to_string() const {
        return "Class_id: " + std::to_string(class_id) + ", Confidence: " + std::to_string(score) + ", Bounding Box: " + bounding_box.to_string();
    }
};

struct Detection {
    BoundingBox bounding_box;
    float score;
    int class_id;
};


// Define ProcessFrameOutput structure
typedef struct ProcessFrameOutput {
    uint32_t size;
    ADROutput* detections;
} ProcessFrameOutput;

enum class Mode : int {
    Default = 1,
};
struct DetectorConfig {
    std::string model_path;
    std::string device;
    double iou_threshold;
    double score_threshold;

    // Constructor
    DetectorConfig(std::string model_path, std::string device, double iou_thresh, double score_thresh)
        : model_path(model_path), device(device), iou_threshold(iou_thresh), score_threshold(score_thresh) {}

    // Default constructor
    DetectorConfig() : model_path(""), device("CPU"), iou_threshold(0.45), score_threshold(0.7) {}

    // Function to get weights path
    std::string weights_path() {
        return model_path + ".bin";
    }
};
struct ADRConfig {
    DetectorConfig detector_config;


};

class ModeAlgorithm {
public:
    virtual std::vector<ADROutput> process_frame(const cv::Mat& frame) = 0;
    virtual void reset() = 0;

    };

class ADR : public ModeAlgorithm {
private:
    DetectorConfig detector;
    ADRConfig config;

public:
    ADR() {}
    
        std::vector<ADROutput> process_frame(const cv::Mat & frame)  {
            std::vector<Detection> detections;
            std::vector<ADROutput> outputs;
           
            return outputs;
        }

    

    void reset()  {
        //debug("Reset called - TBD implement detector reset to intialization state when needed - processing with current config: {}", config.detector_config);
    }

    
};


struct YoloADR {
    ModeAlgorithm* adr_var;

    YoloADR(Mode mode) {
        switch (mode) {
        case Mode::Default:
            adr_var = new ADR();
            break;
        }
    }

    std::vector<ADROutput> process_frame(const Mat& frame) {
        return adr_var->process_frame(frame);
    }

    void reset() {
        adr_var->reset();
    }
};


extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) YoloADR * gpa_initialize(Mode mode);

extern "C"    __declspec(dllexport)  bool gpa_process_frame(YoloADR* adr, uint32_t frame_rows, uint32_t frame_cols, uint32_t frame_stride, void* frame_data, ProcessFrameOutput* detections_out);


extern "C"   __declspec(dllexport) void gpa_drop_detections(ProcessFrameOutput* detections);


extern "C"   __declspec(dllexport)  bool gpa_reset(YoloADR* adr);


extern "C"   __declspec(dllexport) bool gpa_close(YoloADR* adr);


extern "C"   __declspec(dllexport) void pritnline();
```

Source cpp file

```
type here#include <windows.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>.
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <cstring>
#include "pch.h"
#include "gpa_interface.h"

using namespace cv;


YoloADR * gpa_initialize(Mode mode) {
    // logger::setup_logging();
    // debug("Initialize gpa called with mode ", mode);
    return new YoloADR(mode);
}

template<typename T>
void check_for_null_pointer(T* pointer) {
    if (pointer == nullptr) {
        throw std::runtime_error(std::string(typeid(T).name()) + " pointer is null");
    }
}

 bool gpa_process_frame(YoloADR * adr,uint32_t frame_rows,uint32_t frame_cols,uint32_t frame_stride,void* frame_data,ProcessFrameOutput * detections_out)
{

    // debug("Process frame called");
    Mat frame(frame_rows, frame_cols, CV_8UC4, frame_data, frame_stride);
    Mat formatted_frame;
    cvtColor(frame, formatted_frame, COLOR_RGBA2BGR, 3);
    std::vector<ADROutput> detection = adr->process_frame(formatted_frame);
    ADROutput* detection_ptr = detection.data();
    uint32_t size = detection.size();
    ProcessFrameOutput output = {
        output.size = size,
        output.detections = detection_ptr
    };
    std::memcpy(detections_out, &output, sizeof(ProcessFrameOutput));
    return true;
}

void gpa_drop_detections(ProcessFrameOutput * detections) {
    if (detections == nullptr) {
        return;
    }
    delete[] detections->detections;
}

 bool gpa_reset(YoloADR * adr) {
    adr->reset();
    return true;
}

 bool gpa_close(YoloADR * adr)
{
    try {
        //debug("Close called");
        check_for_null_pointer(adr);
        delete adr;
        return true;
    }
    catch (...) {
        return false;
    }
}

 void pritnline()
 {
     std::cout << "print" << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: Make sure you define `MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS` in the preprocessor symbols for your project for the dll only and no other project. My guess is you did not do this essential step and that is what caused your problem.

Comment: `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) YoloADR * gpa_initialize(Mode mode);` should be `extern "C" MATHLIBRARY_API  YoloADR * gpa_initialize(Mode mode);` because this needs to change between `__declspec(dllexport)` when compiling the dll to `__declspec(dllimport)` when using the dll. This is also related to my above comment and how the macro that switches between these 2 works.

Comment: Just as a side note: About [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/whats-the-problem-with-using-namespace-std) – exactly the same applies for the namespace `cv`. Just don't do it, at very least not in a header.

Comment: Did you follow this?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170. Side note